# HttpURLConnection in android app giving me "Source not found" error, can't figure out why

Tags: android

I have this simple line in an AsyncTask class that goes like this:

```
httpconn = (HttpURLConnection)(new URL("http://blynndas.w12.wh-2.com/api/" + params[0]).openConnection());
```

(an example would be "http://blynndas.w12.wh-2.com/api/order")

where params would be the controller name in the Web API that I have.  Anyways, it gives that infernal "Source not found" error, but for the life of me I can't figure out why.

I've looked into many of the similar posts on stackoverflow, but no joy.  Any ideas?

Comment: I often get that error if there is a space or any other character not good for URLs.  It never hurts to use `URLEncoder.encode(params[0])`

Comment: Have you set the internet android permission in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: I'll try the urlencoder idea here in a bit and let you all know.  

Also, I do have the internet permissions in my manifest, but thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

There might be some white space in url which you are using for connection.Check by connecting using static url , if it works then its issue of white space in url.

Comment: Same error whether I am using my url, or http://www.android.com or http://www.google.com

Comment: URL hp = new URL("http://www.google.com"); 
HttpURLConnection hpCon =  (HttpURLConnection) hp.openConnection(); i have tried this , this is working for me, try this & also check in manifest file have you defined internet & wifi permission?